# Background-image for div not displayed

Tags: jquery, html, background-image

I create dynamically below item:

```
     var newItem = '<div title="' + elem.IP + '" id="' + elem.Alias + '-Status" class="elementStatus"><div class="image" id="' + elem.Alias + '-StatusImg" style="height:40px; background-image: ' + '@Url.Content("~/images/ongoing.gif")' + '"></div><div id="' + elem.Alias + '-StatusTxt" class="text">Waiting...</div></div>';
```

then I set background-image for div dynamically as well by performing:

```
$('#' + elem.Alias + '-StatusImg').css("background-image", '@Url.Content("~/images/ongoing.gif")');
```

but background image for div (elem.Alias + '-StatusImg') is not displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing specifically wrong with your javascript, assuming the element is found and the URL of the image is correct. Try `$('#' + elem.Alias + '-StatusImg').length` in the console, it should be `1`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have tried what you have said. Console output is 1 but background image is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `url(x)` in the CSS rule for the background. Try this:

```
$('#' + elem.Alias + '-StatusImg').css("background-image", 'url("@Url.Content("~/images/ongoing.gif")")');
```

Or this:

```
 var newItem = '<div title="' + elem.IP + '" id="' + elem.Alias + '-Status" class="elementStatus"><div class="image" id="' + elem.Alias + '-StatusImg" style="height:40px; background-image: url(@Url.Content("~/images/ongoing.gif))"></div><div id="' + elem.Alias + '-StatusTxt" class="text">Waiting...</div></div>';
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/aqPjg/)

Comment: It works like a charm, but except in one case: initialy I set the background image with your first option, then in a certain point, I perform an ajax call and when call returns ok, I should update the background image again so I use your first option again, but in this last case it is not working, any ideas? (Maybe it is better to open another thread for this?)

Comment: Probably better for another thread, although there's no reason you can't re-use that same line of code. Make sure you include your AJAX code in the new question.

Comment: I posted another thread a few hours ago. I was using img instead of background-image and I was having this problem. So I decided to use background image using divs but I see I continue having the same problem. See below thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658935/image-not-loading-during-heavy-process-ongoing     Note that in setImgTestPassed/Failed now I have the line you have said in your first option.